# MatLab summation of formula

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a program in MatLab which asks user input for n; then proceeds to find the sum of (2n+1)/(n) from 1 to n. Im very new to MatLab so can anyone give me some idea on where to start? Thanks

Comment: read up on [basic matrix operations (assignment / indexing)](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) and also how to use the [`input`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) command. You should be able to use a combination of these to solve this simple problem :)

Comment: If you try a few things and are still stuck, we can give you advice